# A PHP platform to post messages on specific date

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, event-handling, html-email

I am planning to write my first PHP server side code. It includes a scheduler that will email a message to a user on a specific date. The front end of the application is fairly simple.
PHP produces an HTML page where you can select a date in the future to post the message to a an email address.
The question is how would you create an event manager in PHP to handle this? What database would you use? MYSQL or PostgreSQL and why!?

Comment: Have you already searched for this on the Web? What have you already found? Do you still have more precise questions?

Comment: JMax, was that sarcasm? ;)I just recently joint stackoverflow and just getting used asking technical questions. I have to agree that this time I was a bit lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run schedule tasks on server use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). With cron you can run php file that will read data from database and send email.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference MySQL and PostgreSQL can both handle this fine, they are called databases for a reason.

MySQL is more common as a LAMP stack and you will probably find a lot more information on using PHP with MySQL so I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

In regards with the scheduling, you can utilize a cron job if you are using Linux. Windows has a similar service as well.